# Using Plone 4.1 and pas.plugins.sqlalchemy with existing User and Role Table

Tags: plone

I understand that SQLPASPlugin is replace with this product but some of functionality of previous product which I am consfused in pas.plugin.sqlalchemy ?

We have 10K users table and role mapping in existing table and Now we are moving to plone 4 I have installed pas.plugin.sqlachemy. By installing this product creates some new tables (users,...) in database accordingly zcml defination. BUT how can it be used to existing table structure for role and users or map to existing table columns?

Any help would be greatful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 0.3 of pas.plugins.sqlalchemy has functionality to override the model.

Specifically see the section of the Readme.txt:

```
"Custom principal, user and group model"
```

Comment: Thanks for your Help. You always helful.